# PowerShell Send-MailMessage and Microsoft Exchange 2007

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, exchange-server

I'm having a problem sending emails using Microsoft Exchange 2007.

I've used the exact same powershell code on a different machine and it sends the email.

The error message it gives is:

```
Send-MailMessage : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay
At C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Email.ps1:37 char:29
+             Send-MailMessage <<<<  @Parameters
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpFailedRecipientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your receive connector for relaying probably doesn't have the IP address of the computer you are running the script from. You need to check this on the Exchange server.